# BGE ray sensor problem

Tags: game-engine

So I have a object with a ray sensor to it. I've made it that when it hits the object with the property "prop", it will end that object.

The problem is that when I put a few of the "prop" objects on the ground and hit only one of them, the sensor ends every one of them, instead of just the one I shot.

Is there an easy solution to this? Or do I have to learn python?

Thanks!

Comment: Disable X-ray on the ray sensor and only have it fire for one logic tic are the first things that come to mind.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your setup is. Can you post a blend?